# Converting numpy array to rpy2 matrix (forecast package, xreg parameter)

Tags: r, matrix, rpy2

I don't seem to be able to get the line `fit = forecast.Arima(series, order=order, xreg=r_exog_train)` to work. It does work without the xreg parameter so I'm pretty sure it's the numpy array to rpy2 matrix conversion that makes a problem.

Does anyone observe a mistake here? Thanks!

This is the error I get (parts in German unfortunately):

```
Fehler in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = if (ncol(xreg) == 1) nmxreg else paste(n
mxreg,  :
  Länge von 'dimnames' [2] ungleich der Arrayausdehnung
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "r.py", line 58, in <module>
    res = do_forecast(series, horizon=horizon, exog=(exog_train, exog_test))
  File "r.py", line 39, in do_forecast
    fit = forecast.Arima(series, order=order, xreg=exog_train)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\functions.py", line 86, in _
_call__
    return super(SignatureTranslatedFunction, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\functions.py", line 35, in _
_call__
    res = super(Function, self).__call__(*new_args, **new_kwargs)
rpy2.rinterface.RRuntimeError: Fehler in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = if (ncol(
xreg) == 1) nmxreg else paste(nmxreg,  :
  Lõnge von 'dimnames' [2] ungleich der Arrayausdehnung
```

Here is the code example:

```
# Python wrapper for R forecast stuff
import numpy as np

print 'Start importing R.'
from rpy2 import robjects 
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
from rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri import numpy2ri
robjects.conversion.py2ri = numpy2ri

base = importr('base')
forecast = importr('forecast')
stats = importr('stats')
ts = robjects.r['ts']
print 'Finished importing R.'


def nparray2rmatrix(x):
  nr, nc = x.shape
  xvec = robjects.FloatVector(x.transpose().reshape((x.size)))
  xr = robjects.r.matrix(xvec, nrow=nr, ncol=nc)
  return xr

def nparray2rmatrix_alternative(x):
  nr, nc = x.shape
  xvec = robjects.FloatVector(x.reshape((x.size)))
  xr = robjects.r.matrix(xvec, nrow=nr, ncol=nc, byrow=True)
  return xr

def do_forecast(series, frequency=None, horizon=30, summary=False, exog=None):
  if frequency:
    series = ts(series, frequency=frequency)
  else:
    series = ts(series)
  if exog:
    exog_train, exog_test = exog
    r_exog_train = nparray2rmatrix(exog_train)
    r_exog_test = nparray2rmatrix(exog_test)
    order = robjects.IntVector([1, 0, 2]) # c(1,0,2) # TODO find right model
    fit = forecast.Arima(series, order=order, xreg=r_exog_train)
    forecast_result = forecast.forecast(fit, h=horizon, xreg=r_exog_test)
  else:
    # fit = forecast.auto_arima(series)
    #robjects.r.plot(series)
    fit = stats.HoltWinters(series)
    forecast_result = forecast.forecast(fit, h=horizon)
  if summary:
    modsummary = base.summary(fit)
    print modsummary
  forecast_values = np.array(list(forecast_result.rx2('mean')))
  return forecast_values


# Example
series = np.arange(100)
exog_train = np.ones((100,2))
exog_test = np.ones((100,2))
horizon = 100
res = do_forecast(series, horizon=horizon, exog=(exog_train, exog_test))
print res
```

Comment: As a general comment, I would limit the mixing of R into Python as much as possible. Just create the `doforecast` function in R, source the function into the current workspace, and call it. This way you limit the interface of R and Python to just a few lines of R code in Python. This makes it less likely you'll run into rpy specific problems, and makes debugging the R code easier.

Comment: Thanks Paul, that makes sense. Still, I would have the same problem of getting the xreg matrix to work.

Comment: True, but still as a general way of avoiding issues I would make the code as independent of each other as you can.

Comment: I got it working by explicitely stating "dimnames" as in: `xr = robjects.r.matrix(xvec, nrow=nr, ncol=nc, dimnames=dimnames)`.

Comment: You can post this as answer, and accept it. This will inform others that your question has been answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by explicitely stating "dimnames" as in: `xr = robjects.r.matrix(xvec, nrow=nr, ncol=nc, dimnames=dimnames)`. Apparently the forecast package requires this.